# Which best practice in Kotlin for get class simple name

Tags: kotlin

I'm using both ways for get the simple class name in Kotlin, but I don't know which the best.
I often use for logging, so I use only into current class, therefore I use `this` in example bellow.
Someone help me, please.

```
this::class.simpleName
```

OR:

```
this.javaClass.simpleName
```

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? That could mean many different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably more important to pick one method and be consistent. I doubt there is an established best practice on this particular matter (though you never know). It's also unlikely either of these perform better or worse than the other.

That being said, `this.javaclass` will only be available when running on the JVM: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-class.html

Whereas `this::class` I believe is commonly available whether you are targeting JVM, JS or Native. As a rule of thumb, I tend to favor whichever is common across all targets when there is a choice.

Comment: That's a good point.  As a general rule, I think that where Kotlin provides something that Java does as well they have a good reason and the Kotlin way is to be preferred.